# Allow two login methods for the same user in PostgreSQL

Tags: debian, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL server running on a remote Debian Squeeze server. I would like to login with the user *postgres* using the **ident** and **md5** method at the same time. The former is needed for debian maintenance. The latter for connecting my local postgresql client through ssh port forwarding.

My first aproach was to add to lines with the user postgress like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
local   all         postgres                          ident
local   all         postgres                          md5
```

This apparently doesn't work and the official documentation explains:

> The first record with a matching connection type, client address,
>   requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication.
>   There is no "fall-through" or "backup": if one record is chosen and
>   the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered. If no
>   record matches, access is denied.

Because the first three columns are the same postgresql will simply chose the first it encounters.

My workaround is to create a second superuser named root

```
CREATE ROLE root LOGIN SUPERUSER CREATEROLE CREATEDB PASSWORD 'newpassword';
```

and put the following into pg_hba.conf:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
local   all         postgres                          ident
local   all         root                              md5
```

Is there a better solution without creating the second user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're connecting via port forwarding, your connection is going to be a `host` type connection anyway, and should be configured as such.   I assume this connection would be from `127.0.0.1/32` so you'd configure

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD
local   all         postgres                          ident
host    all         postgres    127.0.0.1/32          md5
```

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately:`# psql --username postgres --password --host localhost
Password for user postgres: 
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Comment: By default `postgres` has no password and you need to provide one before connecting with the md5 method, otherwise you get the error message above. Same as if you type a wrong password.

Comment: I changed the password with `ALTER ROLE postgres WITH PASSWORD 'MYPASSWORD';`

Comment: I tested this on a new server and it works. Must have been some error on my part. I am accepting this answer. It might be also worth noting, that PostgresSQL does not really use `ident` but falls back on `peer` since almost nobody has an ident server running.